# What does this symbol mean in ES6?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

Why is `JSDOM` wrapped in `{` `}`?
Could anyone tell me what it means in ES6?

```
const jsdom = require("jsdom");
const { JSDOM } = jsdom;
```

Comment: [Destructuring assignment.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)

Comment: Could you tell me why use destructuring assignment in this instance?@Pointy

Comment: It's shorter than `const JSDOM = jsdom.JSDOM;`